# Asp.Net MVC Unique id per request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In our MVC 5 site, no session, we need to get/generate a unique ID per request. THhis will be used as an ID for logging all activity in the request.

Is there a way to assign/get a value to a Request to enable this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [log4net unique request id in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842321/log4net-unique-request-id-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add it to the request item collection odetocode.com/articles/111.aspx

```
Guid.NewGuid()
```

Will generate a unique id.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: But how do I attached it to a Request so that it is accessible in the entire lifecycle of the request.

Answer (score 8):

Here's some extension methods that I created for this purpose:

```
public static Guid GetId(this HttpContext ctx) => new HttpContextWrapper(ctx).GetId();

public static Guid GetId(this HttpContextBase ctx)
{
    const string key = "tq8OuyxHpDgkRg54klfpqg== (Request Id Key)";

    if (ctx.Items.Contains(key))
        return (Guid) ctx.Items[key];

    var mutex = string.Intern($"{key}:{ctx.GetHashCode()}");
    lock (mutex)
    {
        if (!ctx.Items.Contains(key))
            ctx.Items[key] = Guid.NewGuid();

        return (Guid) ctx.Items[key];
    }
}
```

#Update

@Luiso made a comment about interned strings not being garbage collected. This is a good point. In a very busy web app that doesn't recycle app pools frequently enough (or ever) this would be a serious issue.

Thankfully, recent versions of .NET have ephemeron support via the `ConditionalWeakTable<TK,TV>` class. Which gives a convenient and memory safe way of tackling this problem:

```
       private static readonly ConditionalWeakTable<object, ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>>
        Ephemerons = new ConditionalWeakTable<object, ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>>();

    public static Guid GetId(this HttpContext ctx)
    {
        var dict = Ephemerons.GetOrCreateValue(ctx);
        var id = (Guid)dict.GetOrAdd(
            "c53fd485-b6b6-4da9-9e9d-bf30500d510b",
            _ => Guid.NewGuid());
        return id;
    }

    public static Guid GetId(this HttpContextBase ctx)
    {
        // this is slow and subject to breaking change; TODO: smart things to mitigate those problems
        var innerContext = (HttpContext)ctx.GetType().GetField("_context", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(ctx);
        return innerContext.GetId();
    }
```

My [Overby.Extensions.Attachments](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Overby.Extensions.Attachments/) package has an extension method that simplify things.

```
/// <summary>
/// Unique identifier for the object reference.
/// </summary>
public static Guid GetReferenceId(this object obj) =>
    obj.GetOrSetAttached(() => Guid.NewGuid(), RefIdKey);
```

Using that extension method, you would just call `httpContext.GetReferenceId()`.

Comment: why are you using `string.Intern` for the mutex here?

Comment: Because it produces an object references that I don't have to keep track of. I talk more about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29878495/64334

Comment: @RonnieOverby won't interning so many strings (one per request) have a negative impact on memory usage, since interned strings are not garbage collected and will remain in the pool until it is restarted?

Comment: The post is old, but why do you wrap the context in an HttpContextWrapper for getting the id?

Comment: @Sam No idea what I was thinking because that obviously gives you a different instance of the wrapper class and therefore a different Id.

Comment: @Sam I updated the code so that it's not as busted as before, though I would cache the delegate that get's the private field value and make an automated test to prove that the reflection works at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a single value without having to implement something like `Guid.NewGuid()`, perhaps the `HttpContext` timestamp will work for you.

```
int requestId = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Timestamp.Ticks;
```

A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond, or 10 million ticks in a second.

**Then this solution should be evaluated according to their circumstances because there is the possibility that two requests fall on the same tick of time.**