# Application Insights - Get telemetry's ItemId after calling TrackException()

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

Upon unexpected error which sends the user to an error page, I want to show an error id for the user to give to the customer support for further investigation.

Telemetries has itemId which is unique (guid). Is there a to fetch this itemId (or any other unique identifier) right after I track the exception telemetry?

As a workaround I thought about generating my own unique identifier and adding it to the telemetry's custom properties, but it seems like I can't look up a telemetry by a custom property.

```
    private string LogTelemetry(Exception ex)
    {
        var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();
        var telemetry = new ExceptionTelemetry(ex);

        telemetryClient.TrackException(telemetry);

        //here I want to be able to return the telemetry's unique identifier
    }
```

Comment: Hi Yarinsn, where do you find the itemId? I did not find it in code or azure portal. Or can you use the  `Context.Operation.Id` as unique identifier?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Ivan. I use Application Insights Analytics to analyze my logs (on VS, right-click the project in question -> Application Insights -> Application Analytics will open the tool in the browser). Over there, when I query my exceptions, one of the exception's fields is itemId, which is a Guid.
About `Context.Operation.Id`, it's null in my case - Thoughts regarding that

Comment: I will take a try with app insights API to fetch Itemid, and will let you know if it works.

Comment: please take a look at my answer below

Comment: does it work for you?

Comment: Using the REST api doesn't help in my case but I appreciate your detailed answer. About the link you shared regarding the operation_id, it helped me look at my situation in a different way, which resulted in me solving my problem. I will share my solution soon. Thanks for your help Ivan!

Comment: Congrats and thanks for your sharing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my solution for this problem is comprised of two parts:

1. Adding a unique identifier (Guid) to every request using `HttpContext.Current.Items` (based on one of the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842321/log4net-unique-request-id-in-asp-net) SO question) on my app's `Application_BeginRequest`.
2. Acquiring the request's unique identifier upon logging an exception, assigning it to the `TelemetryClient`'s operation id, which is being assigned to the telemetry object, and returning it.

   ```
   private string LogTelemetry(Exception ex)
   {
       var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();
       var telemetry = new ExceptionTelemetry(ex);

       var operationId = HttpContext.Current.Items["RequestIdentity"].ToString();
       telemetryClient.Context.Operation.Id = operationId;

       telemetryClient.TrackException(telemetry);

       return operationId;
   }
   ```

Note that I didn't use `System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current.RootId` as the telemetry's operation id because the `Current` object was null in my case, a problem I decided not to tackle at this point.

Answer (score 0):

1.The ItemId can be fetched by using Application Insights REST API, but it has some time(around a few minutes) delay in runtime. The code is in the following.

2.Without using ItemId, you can use the operation_id, in your code, just use this line of code `return System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current.RootId`, here is reference about [operation_id](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/444)

3.Example for using APP Insights REST API:

3.1 Getting your API key and Application ID, details [here](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Authorization/API-key-and-App-ID):
Nav to azure portal -> go to your application insights -> under `configure` section, select `API Access` -> Write down the application id, then click Create API Key, screenshot below, remember write down the key:
[image]

3.2 Construct the [api url](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Overview/URL-formats), like this:

```
https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/your_application_id/query?,
```

then construct your query string:

```
query=exceptions | where timestamp >= datetime("UTC time") | where operation_Id == "operation_id"
```

you can modify the query as you need.

3.3 My code as following, it returns json string, you can parse json to get ItemId:

```
public string MakeException()

{

    try
    {
        int zipcode = int.Parse("123er");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        DateTime dt = DateTime.UtcNow;
        string timeFormat = dt.ToString("s"); 

        telemetry.TrackException(ex);
        telemetry.Flush();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));  // in runtime, need to wait for the result populated           

        string operation_id = System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current.RootId; //get the operation_id, will use it in the query string

        string api = "https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/your_application_id/query?";
        string query = @"query=exceptions | where timestamp >= datetime(""" + timeFormat + @""")";
        query += " | where operation_Id == " + "\"" + operation_id + "\"";
        api += query;

        string apikey = "your api key";

        //call the REST API
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", apikey);
        var req = string.Format(api);
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(req).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; // return a json string, you can parse it to get the ItemId
        }
        else
        {
            return response.ReasonPhrase;
        }


    }

    return "ok";
}
```